# Build xPath query using javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery in Hibernate?

Tags: sql-server, xml, hibernate

I want to get records from MS SQL server database where I have XML type column called xmlData.

I want to execute query with condition: `/record/mark = 5`similary to:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("From Test WHERE xmlData.value('(/record/mark)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '5'");
List list = query.list();
```

xmlData column structure:

```
<record>
  <name>John</name>
  <mark>5</mark>
</record>
```

My code:

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Test> criteria = builder.createQuery( Test.class );
        Root<Test> root = criteria.from( Test.class );
        criteria.select( root );
        criteria.where( builder. ); // <- how to biuld query ? 
        Test yourObject = session.createQuery( criteria ).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the Java parts but I can do the sql-server part.

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE xmlData.exist ( '/record/mark[text() = "5"]' ) = 1
```

This is faster because we are performing all the string matching inside the XQuery

But this might not be suitable as it stands for you data. Because you wanted a value you were forced to specify the first instance `[1]` in your query. This code will match something with multiple marks where the first isn't five but a subsequent one is. Obviously this may be an irrelevance in your use case.

```
<record>
  <name>Louise</name>
  <mark>10</mark>
  <mark>5</mark>
</record>
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8775f0/1/0)